# How to navigate user to another app on his device?

Tags: flutter, dart, url, deep-linking

I have an app where users can buy tickets using a Bank mobile application.
I make a request to bank servers and get a **url** for the user to be re-directed and complete his transaction in the bank app.

So my question is.. What can I use for this situation? should I use deeplinks or just a url_luncher. What is the optimal solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use deep-link for only Android you can use this package for it
https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus

But if you want to use for both os, you must be use this code;

```
void launchAppWithUniversalLink() async {
  final url = 'https://example.com'; // Replace with your app's universal link

  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

**!IMPORTANT!**

**Apple / iOS:** If you use the universal URL for deep-link Apple domain check service can take 24 hours for your domain configuration. And you must follow more detail on [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html).

**Google / Android:** App Link / Deep-Link Google Play wants a JSON file like Apple. You must store your deep-link domain in these JSON configurations. You can find more information about verifying your deep link on [Google Play Store Developer Console](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks)

**Please DO NOT FORGET:** If you want to test everything on your local device like an emulator or physical device with debug-apk. You must add a fingerprint to the well-known JSON file. If you don't add this fingerprint to your json, your application is not opened when you run to deep-link on the device. You will redirect to system default browser.

**One More Thing:**
Your application needs more security for the deep links. You must use a self prefix like "myapp://" you have more chance for stable working with deep-link. But when your app is installed on the device. You can use this deep-link url to open your application.

Android side has more solutions. But iOS does not have more solution like Android. If I develop an application like this, I choose the self-prefix version for deep-link. It's more secure and easily manage.